# Conceptual question about set theory fundamentals: Tao's Analysis I Chapter 3

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In Tao's *Analysis I*, Chapter $3$ introduces the fundamentals of set theory. In particular, the following lemma and axiom are provided (in this order...i.e. lemma precedes the axiom in the chapter layout):

---

> Lemma (Single Choice): *Let $A$ be a non-empty set. Then there exists an object $x$ such that $x \in A$*

There is an accompanying mini-proof by contradiction that establishes this.

---

> Axiom (Singleton sets and pair sets): *If $a$ is an object, then there exists a set $\{a\}$ whose only element is $a$, i.e. for every object $y$, we have $y \in \{a\}$ if and only if $y=a$; we refer to $\{a\}$ as the singleton set whose element is $a$. Furthermore, if $a$ and $b$ are objects, then there exists a set $\{a,b\}$ whose only elements are $a$ and $b$; i.e. for every object $y$, we have $y \in \{a,b\}$ if and only if $y=a$ or $y=b$; we refer to this set as the pair formed by $a$ and $b$.*

---

The aim of this question is not meant to be pedantic; I want to make sure I am understanding the difference between the two statements...because the order of presentation has me slightly confused.

It seems to me that it would have made more sense to present the **Axiom (Singleton sets and pair sets)** first because this is effectively establishing the existence of sets beyond just the empty set (which was stated one page earlier)...i.e. this establishes that "non-empty sets" exist (albeit, only non-empty sets containing one or two elements).

The lemma seems like it is already baked into this axiom...for example, the singleton set $\{a\}$ is literally defined by $a\in\{a\}$ and the pair set is literally defined by $a\in \{a,b\}$. And this is sort of why I am confused.

Why is there a need for this lemma when the axiom essentially already states this? Moreover, I am anticipating that all sets are effectively "derived" from the union of singleton and pair sets...and therefore, once again, the axiom already encodes the lemma, even for non-empty sets greater than size $1$ and $2$.

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, the Axiom 3.2 (not stated in your question) assumes the empty set. 
Then, the Lemma 3.1.6 (Single Choice) is derived (`If A is a non-empty set, then ... `) Note that it doesn't prove A exists. (but rather: if A exists, then it will have some properties.)
Finally, Axiom 3.3 (singleton/pair sets) assumes A exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tao's system there are more than one "sort" of mathematical objects; numbers, sets, functions.

For simplicity, consider natural numbers: we have numbers: $0,1,2,\ldots$ and *sets* of numbers: $\{ 0 \}, \{ 1,3,5,\ldots \}$, etc.

The author assumes the existence of sets: at least one, the *empty set* (**Axiom 3.2**).

For every non-empty set $A$ (if any) we can always pick one object $x$ belonging to $A$: $x \in A$.

The proof is trivial, using the definition of empty set: $\forall x \ \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$, and the (stated see (*why?*)) fact that the empty set is unique.

Assume that the lemma to be proved is false, i.e. that $\lnot \exists x (x \in A)$; but this is the definition of empty set. Thus, $A= \emptyset$, contradicting the assumption that $A$ is not empty.

Having assumed (**Axiom 3.2**) that at least one set exists is not enough for our purpose; thus, in order to develop mathematics, we have to "produce" more sets from the existing stuff (up to now: the empty set and numbers).

How to do this ? With further axioms that we can classify as:

- "conditional existence" axioms, i.e. axioms producing new sets from existing ones:

> **Axiom 3.3** (Singleton sets and pair sets), as well as **Axiom 3.5** (Axiom of specification).

With them we can generate e.g. $\{ \emptyset \}$, i.e. a set with one element, and then apply the trivial **Lemma** above to conclude that: $\emptyset \in \{ \emptyset \}$;

- "unconditional existence" axioms, i.e. axioms asserting the existence of brand new sets:

> **Axiom 3.7** (Infinity): There exists a set $\mathbb N$, whose elements are the natural numbers.

This is a much more interesting axiom for mathematics: we have that $0 \in \mathbb N, 1 \in \mathbb N$, etc. In addition, using Specification, we may prove that the set $\{ 0,1 \}$ exists (it is a subset of $\mathbb N$), and much more using other "conditional" axioms.

See e.g. [Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html) and [Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html).